# Can't receive mail from outside domain

Tags: server, mx, mail

Grr. This is annoying.

- I **can** send/receive email locally *(eg. joe@example.com <-> sue@example.com)*
- I **can't** send/receive email to/from other domains *(eg. joe@hotmail.com <-> sue@example.com)*

Everything was working OK until I installed/set-up CloudFlare, and since then I haven't been able to sent or receive to/from other domains.

- CloudFlare and my host both say the MX record is pointing to 'mail.example.com' with a Priority 0.

Thanks for any help!
PS: My host is GoDaddy.

Answer (score 3):

I posted my plea for help a bit too soon. LOL.

To get it working:

1. Delete MX record on cPanel and CloudFlare,
2. Create new MX record with Priority 1 pointing to `mail.example.com` on cPanel and CloudFlare.

So, all is working again. Phew.

Though, I have noticed that email from `Outlook.com` comes in instantly, while mail from Gmail takes about 20 mins to arrive. Who knows why.

Comment: It may be GMail. Some e-mail SMTP servers work in intervals and mot real-time. While the e-mail may be queued, it may one to a few minutes for each step of the process. I assume that GMail should be faster. However, it may be that GMail is busy and set it's interval times up due to volume making it less real-time. I have no idea what is normal for GMail. If GMail times are consistent, I would say do not worry about it. It is free e-mail.